# Logarithmic Limits

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate:

$$\lim _{n\to +\infty} {\left(2^\frac12-2^\frac13\right)}{\left(2^\frac12 - 2^\frac 15\right)}\dots{\left(2^\frac 12 -2^\frac {1}{2n-1}\right)}$$

First of all I would talk about its official solution that has been given by making an inequality. My first approach to this question would be by taking logarithm and it is not helping me out in the formation of any indeterminate forms , What could be another possible approach for this question except inequality. Thanks:)

Comment: @peterwhy looks like taking log but ended in squeeze theorem

Comment: For completeness, I guess the official squeeze of the required limit would be between $0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(2^{1/2}-1\right)^n = 0.4142\ldots^\infty = 0$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $a_n={(2^\frac12-2^\frac13)}$$\times$${(2^\frac12 - 2^\frac 15)}$$.....$${(2^\frac 12 -2^\frac {1}{2n-1})}  ~~,n>1$

Then

$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}= \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{(2^\frac 12 -2^\frac {1}{2n+1})}<1$

So $\sum {a_n}$ converges and hence $a_n\mapsto 0$

Comment: Ah, RATIO test! you beat me to it!!!

Comment: @Meet Patel why did you take ratio ? is it any theorem or property ?

Comment: @πααρτθ Σαρθι the ratio is motived by the fact it's an infinite product so the ratios will be easy to calculate.

Comment: @πααρτθΣαρθι  Yes . [RATIO TEST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test)

Comment: @MeetPatel Got it !

Comment: this is a very bad way IMO to show that the limit is $0$ for someone who is learning the topic. i'd bluntly claim that someone who couldn't solve the problem isn't learning anything new with your answer.  a much more clear way would be to show that $\vert a_n\vert<B c^n$ for some constant $B$ and some $0<c<1$ which would take one more sentence.